# How to turn Sequence of images into video using DirectShow filters?

Tags: c#, c++, video, image, directshow

How to turn Sequence of images into video using DirectShow filters?
I have image A and image B and image C. I want to create a DirectShow graph (Using GraphEdit or with C\C++\C# for example) to create a video of 3 frames in duration where first frame is image A second image B and so on =) 
How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the Push Source Filters Sample from MSDN:
[MSDN Push Source Filter sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd377481%28VS.85%29.aspx)